# Activity lifecycle method on app crash

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a method of the Activity lifecycle that is guaranteed to get called when my app crashes?

I put logs in all methods and crashed my app but I didn't see anything.

I couldn't find anything in the docs too.

I basically want to save changes in a database but ideally I do not want to do it in every update but rather in a method like onPause or onStop etc.

Comment: You should not execute any important business logic in onPause, onStop, etc.

Comment: @user1199931 Thanks, however is there any other place of saving state if I don't want to do it everytime a record changes?

Comment: Why don't you want to save it every time a record changes? That would be the simplest option.

Comment: No, if you're concerned with losing uncommitted changes due to unexpected crashes, you should save as often as possible.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I am basically writing in a text file and I am worried about concurrency issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the lifecycle methods will be called if your `Activity` crashes.

However, for child activities started using `startActivityForResult` you do get a `RESULT_CANCELED` code returned in `onActivityResult` on the parent `Activity`.